# Lambda expression and it's code equalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Is this code

```
GLOBAL_VERSION = '1'
def get_version():
    return GLOBAL_VERSION
 mod_version=get_version()
```

is equal to

```
GLOBAL_VERSION = '1'

mod_version=lambda **_: GLOBAL_VERSION
```

or not?

Thank you very much!

Comment: no because the first `mod_version` is a function call, the latter is a function. and you don't need `**_`. Just omit it

Comment: In the first case you're calling the function and getting the result back, in the second case you make a lambda and bind it to the name `mod_version`.

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not.

In the first version you have a global variable (`GLOBAL_VERSION`), a function (`get_version`), and another global variable (`mod_version`).

In the second you have a global variable (`GLOBAL_VERSION`) and a function (`mod_version`).

Probably the most important difference between the two is that `mod_version` is set to the `str` `'1'` in the first and a function that returns the `str` `'1'` in the second.

Definitely not the same.

*Side note*  if the lambda doesn't need any parameters, don't define any:

```
some_func = lambda: GLOBAL_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, lambdas are different than functions. A good example for a difference is when trying to `pickle` them. Functions are pickleable, but lambdas aren't:

```
import pickle

def func():
    return 0

lam = lambda: 1

print(func())
print(lam())

print(pickle.dumps(func))
print(pickle.dumps(lam))
```

This code will print `0`, `1`, something that helps it locate `func`, and then error on the last line (`Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7fa30118e048>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed`).